# array binding with Npgsql

Tags: .net, npgsql

Is there a way to do bulk operations with npgsql like with ODP.NET array binding feature ? 
I am aware of the Batching/Pipelining/multiple SQL statements in a single command (executing in a single roundtrip) but as far as I understand you can't use it in the same way, with different parameters for every statement. If it can be done, I would be happy if someone could provide an example how to convert the code below to Npgsql.

```
List<dto> listDTO; // list containing up to 1000 dtos

OraCommand = db.GetOracleCommand();
OraCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, FIELD1, FIELD2) VALUES (:ID, :FIELD1, :FIELD2)";

object[] FIELD1 = new object[listDTO.Count];
object[] FIELD2 = new object[listDTO.Count];

for (int i = 0; i <= listDTO.Count - 1; i++)
{
    ID[i] = listDTO.Id;
    FIELD1[i] = listDTO.Field1;
    FIELD2[i] = listDTO.Field2;                    
}
OraCommand.ArrayBindCount = listDTO.Count;

OraCommand.Parameters.Add(":ID", OracleDbType.Decimal, ID, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
OraCommand.Parameters.Add(":FIELD1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10, FIELD1, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
OraCommand.Parameters.Add(":FIELD2", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 32, FIELD2, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);

db.DoSqlPrepareCommand(OraCommand);
```

Edit: 
This is how I think it should best be done using Npgsql:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("connString");
conn.Open();    
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand();    
string CommandText = "";

for (int i = 0; i <=5 ; i++)
{
    CommandText = CommandText + "INSERT INTO testtbl (id, field1) VALUES (@ID_" + i + " , @FIELD1_" + i + ");";

    command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("ID_" + i, i));
    command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("FIELD1_" + i, "FIELD1" + i));
}
command.CommandText = CommandText;
command.Connection = conn;
int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is bulk insert of many rows, you should look at [binary COPY](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html) - this is definitely the most efficient method.

Otherwise it's definitely possible to prepare your INSERT statement and then batch/pipeline its execution with different parameters in the same roundtrip. This will yield very good performance, although still not as good as binary COPY.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I want to insert new rows/objects so I think I have to go with prepared INSERT statements. 
So I will have to create separate parameter names for each of the statements instead of using arrays as with odp.net (I guess that's how odp.net is working behind the scenes...)

Comment: Inserting new rows/objects doesn't mean that you have to go with prepared INSERT statements - anything you can do with (simple) INSERT statements you can also do with COPY, except the latter would be more efficient. It will also save you the trouble of having to deal with parameter names. It's a good idea to read the docs I pointed to.

Comment: As soon as you need the resulting serials, COPY is no longer an option. Batched statements also work for UPSERT and similar statements. You have more control over what is happening when using batched statements.