# Array Binding Implementation over NpgSql

Tags: nhibernate, npgsql, postgresql-9.4

I am working on Npgsql with Nhibernate over .Net for PostgreSQL query generation and also migration from oracle,

And I confused about “array binding” via NpgSql
I found some discussion  [array binding with Npgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260860/array-binding-with-npgsql) and seems solution is standard bulk insert

Below the sample query;

```
INSERT INTO <table_name>(C1,C2) VALUES (1, :V01);, V01: "System.String[]"
```

At oracle seems odp.net have some array binding implementation for bulk insert([Bulk Data Insertion into Oracle Database in C#](https://dzone.com/articles/bulk-data-insertion-oracle)).

At the Npgsql is there any implementation about array binding or maybe on road-map?
(Note: Npgsql version is 3.2.7 , Nhibernate v4.0.4.4000 and finally Postgresql version 9.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PostgreSQL has [first-class support for parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html), Npgsql allows you to pass an array as a single parameter value (i.e. just like you can have a string column, you can have an array column).

However, there's no automatic way to do bulk insert from an array - you're going to have to write the loop yourself. The most efficient way to do that is to use [the bulk insert binary COPY API](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html). Otherwise you could concatenate multiple INSERT statements inside the same DbCommand (delimited by semicolons), although that would be less efficient.

I don't think that bulk insert from array would make a lot of sense, since PostgreSQL doesn't support anything like it at the protocol level. So if we did this, Npgsql would simply be implementing the loop instead of the user (pure sugar), and in general we try to stay low-level and only expose PostgreSQL functionality.